# MongoDB query for today and tomorrow events

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to come up with a MongoDB(v 3.6.7.) query for finding documents that match specific criteria -  events that start today or tomorrow (without manual input of today's date)

This is example field:

```
"StartDateTime" : "2018-11-08T00:32:00Z"
```

I've tried something which should return at least some of the events, but can't figure out why it is not working

```
db.collection.find({ StartDateTime: { $gte: new Date() } })
```

Can anyone help me with this query?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Here's a link to the query operators I used:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/

```
// Get date strings
const startTime = new Date(Date.now());
const startTimeString = startTime.getFullYear() + '-' + ((startTime.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' : '') + startTime.getMonth()) + '-' + ((startTime.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + startTime.getDate()) + 'T' + '00:00:00.000Z';

const startTimeTomorrow = new Date(Date.now());
startTimeTomorrow.setDate(startTimeTomorrow.getDate() + 1);
const startTimeTomorrowString = startTimeTomorrow.getFullYear() + '-' + ((startTimeTomorrow.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' : '') + startTimeTomorrow.getMonth()) + '-' + ((startTimeTomorrow.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + startTimeTomorrow.getDate()) + 'T' + '23:59:59.999Z';

// MongoDB Find Query (returns cursor)
db.collection.find({ 
    'StartDateTime': { 
        '$gte': startTimeString,
        '$lte': startTimeTomorrowString
    } 
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code it works, but you must add +1 on month, because MongoDB returns months from 0, ie. January is 0... 
My second problem is how to create Mongo VIEW with variables

Comment: You would just set the find () equal to  a variable and string a toArray() call to the end of find () to get everything as a JavaScript array.